# EPPlus - Exporting string values with leading single quotation mark

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I am trying to write data with C# and EPPlus library to an xlsx-File. Works fine so far, BUT: The values I write all have to start with a single quotation mark ('). If I write that one to a cell (e.g. "'MyName"), and afterwards open the Excel file in Excel, the ' is displayed in all the cells! Normally, when you write this leading quotation mark in Excel, it is not shown in the cells, only in the formula.
In my case, if I go to a cell, edit the formula and hit "Return", the normal behaviour is back. But not after the export, and of course hitting return on all cells is not an option.

Any ideas? I googled quite a lot without success...

```
WorkSheet.Cells[1, 4].Value = "'nameFirstname";
WorkSheet.Cells[1, 5].Value = "'1";
```

Comment: Post your code so others can have a look at it.

Comment: The code is nothing special, but here we go: `WorkSheet.Cells[1, 4].Value = "'nameFirstname"; WorkSheet.Cells[1, 5].Value = "'1";` and so on (@Ernie)

Comment: Thanks @Ernie, seems I cannot (yet) update my questions... In the meantime, I tried setting some different fields instead of "Value" (e.g. Formula), but no change...

Comment: Why do you need the single quote at all?  Your code should work fine without them including the `1` value will be stored as text.

Comment: Yes, right, BUT: The system for which I write the Excel-file wants to have the leading ' - do not ask me why, it is a quite old system. Anyway, I wonder where the difference is between writing the ' via EPPlus, or via writing it directly in Excel. Somewhere they have to store the ' when you write it in the formula.... Strange...

Comment: that requirement to put a single quote before each string will likely be due to "force Excel to interpret everything as text". In EPPlus, you have better tools to achieve that (cell style, number format, ...). I second the thought of @Ernie and recommend to figure that out and get the requirement changed.

Comment: Sure you have - but what I am doing is to re-build an example-Excel-file. Any my result should look exactly like this example...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments I understand now.  To include the single quote recognized by Excell set the option like this:

```
ws.Cells[1, 4].Value= "namefirstname";  //No single quote needed
ws.Cells[1, 4].Style.QuotePrefix = true;
```

Comment: Wow, cool! Thank you very much!! It seems I also was on the wrong EPPlus version, 4.0.5. The part with the QuotePrefix is only available in 4.1 - I update recommended. After that, it worked like a charm. Thanks again!